# How change reverse order NSMutableArray stored values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have creating button click to change `Tableview` values totally reverse.

For example :

Normal tableview

```
----------------------------------------------
 Name           A             B            C
----------------------------------------------
 anis            20           20          1
----------------------------------------------
 dols            30           30           2
----------------------------------------------
```

`Button first click` to change `tableview column` values like below

```
----------------------------------------------
 Name          A             B            C
----------------------------------------------
 dols            30           30           2
----------------------------------------------
 anis            20            20          1
----------------------------------------------
```

`Button second click` to change tableview column again normal position

`FYI :` Here above tableview multiple `custom cell` label with multiple `NSMutableArray`, I am using for some reason.

I had successfully completed Name reverse order changing by below code

```
names  = [[[alertArray allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:keys ascending:NO]]] mutableCopy];
```

But now I need `"How to change reverse cell other values A B C like above diagram 2`(Its not sorting work).

Here below code to I have storing separate values into separate `NSMutableArrays`.

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = .....;

    for (NSString *keys in sortedKeys) {
        [name_array addObject:keys];
        [A_array addObject:[alertArray objectForKey:keys][@"A"]];
        [B_array addObject:[alertArray objectForKey:keys][@"B"]];
        [C_array addObject:[alertArray objectForKey:keys][@"C"]];
   }
```

Comment: Show cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

Comment: do not do add subview in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying you have the data for each column in a seperate array, wish to sort one of those columns, and then wish to mutate the other arrays to match? Show your code, right now people trying to help can only guess.

Comment: Its big one...Sorry I cant post here!@Arpit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are filling up the data to your tableview from array `myTableViewArray`.

In the methods where you are switching it

```
myTableViewArray = [[[myTableViewArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]mutableCopy];
[myCustomTableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
reversedArray = [[theMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

**OR**

> You can also use the NSSortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDes = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your key" ascending:YES];
[_array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDes]];
```

**OR**

```
[tableAry sortUsingDescriptors:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];

    NSLog(@"tableAry : %@",tableAry);
```

**OR**

```
[tableAry sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(DataModel *obj1, DataModel *obj2) {
        return [obj1.name caseInsensitiveCompare:obj2.name];
}];
```

Comment: @AnswerMe After changing datasource call `reloadData:` method of tableView.

Comment: @AnswerMe, After sorting.. Try using [tableView reloadData]; (where tableView is the name of your instance variable)

Comment: @AnswerMe, how you using array in Table ?, i think you have to manage Table as per Array .